# python rename header row after w.writerow is finished

Tags: python

In the below script, I cannot figure out how to either rename or "faux-rename" the headers.

```
import csv,time,string,os

print "rendering report.  This will take a few minutes..."

raw_report = "\\\\network\\x\\RAWREPORT.csv"
today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

fields = ["As of Date", "EB", "Cycle", "Col", "APP Name", "Home Country" ]

with open(raw_report) as infile, open("c:\\upload\\test_" + today + ".csv", "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, extrasaction="ignore")
    w.writeheader()
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)
```

This script works fine, and it takes 6 columns out of a .csv with about 90 columns, but in order to write only those 6 columns in `fields` to my output file, I need to call them by name.

However, I need them to ultimately be named something different., (e.g. - `"order_date", "phone_number"...` instead of `"As of Date", "EB"`).

I tried the approach of just skipping the first row and writing my own:

```
r = csv.DictReader(infile)
w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, extrasaction="ignore")
next(r, None)
w.writerow(["order_date","phone_number",...])
```

but then python doesn't know which columns to copy into the new file because the names don't match.

How would I go about doing what I'm trying to do?  Can I reference the columns I want to copy by number instead of by name, or is there a way to go back and change the value of the first row once everything is copied?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this incorrectly.  I can define `fields` as the columns in the original file to pull from, but I don't need to include those necessarily in the output file as they are two separate files.

This code works:

```
fields = ["As of Date", "EB", "Cycle", "Col", "APP Name", "Home Country" ]
with open(raw_report) as infile, open("c:\\upload\\test_" + today + ".csv", "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, extrasaction="ignore")
    #w.writeheader() #remove the writeheader command

    #write our custom header
    wtr = csv.writer( outfile )    
    wtr.writerow(["order_date", "phone_number", etc....])

    #then, write the rest of the file
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)
```